# Python: How can I stop my function values from changing after my first call (time series)

Tags: python, function, time-series, call

I have:

```
np.random.seed(123)
def v_t(var_v, T):
    v_t_ = np.zeros([T,1])
    v_t_[1:T] = (var_v ** 0.5) * np.random.randn(len(v_t_) - 1, 1)
    return v_t_

def s_t(rho, T):
    v_t_ = v_t(var_v, T)
    s_t_ = np.zeros([T,1])
    s_t_[0] = 0
    for t in range(1,T):
        s_t_[t] = rho *s_t_[t-1] + v_t_[t]
    return s_t_
```

However every time I call one of the values, i.e.

```
s_t(rho, T)       "or"         v_t(var_v, T)
```

the right value is shown. But directly afterwards, when I call the other value, the value is wrong. (Probably due to some time series effect.) After I clear my namespace, when I call the functions in the mirrored sequence, the same holds true. How do I get the right values displayed for every call without resetting the namespace???

Would be great to hear from you! Cheers, Tobias

Comment: Don't name variables the same as functions.

Comment: Do you have  a example in my code?

Comment: `s_t` and `v_t`

Comment: maybe s_t_ =  = np.zeros([T,1]) instead of s_t ?

Comment: okay I try it out, thank you!

Comment: I got     `def v_t(var_v, T):
    # Getting draws of the shock realizations
    v_t_ = np.zeros([T,1])
    # Specification for stochastic realizations:
    v_t_[1:T] = (var_v ** 0.5) * np.random.randn(len(v_t_) - 1, 1)
    return v_t_

def s_t(rho, T):
    # Generating the sequence of autocorrelated productivity states
    v_t_2 = v_t(var_v, T)
    s_t_ = np.zeros([T,1])
    s_t_[0] = 0
    for t in range(1,T):
        s_t_[t] = rho *s_t_[t-1] + v_t_2[t]
    return s_t_
` But it does not work either....

Comment: Just to clarify, I was stating a general programming rule i.e it isn't the solution but it's a clean-up.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood that. Nonetheless, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem concerns with the np.random.randn(len(v_t_) - 1, 1)...